# Paypal NVP Api dead only from a specifc server.

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

And in Dead I mean: absolutly no response. request Timeout when posting (or doing anything else) to the api at: `https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp`

Instead of getting a wrong answer:

`ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error`
for an empy method. or the right answer (with an encrypted button) to the right api call.

Could this be a blacklist issue for the specific server? I checked and at least as I could tell there is no firewall difference between the specfic server configuration and out other servers (with other domains) that work just fine.

I found this [reference](http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?207238-%2828%29-connect%28%29-timed-out-https-api-3t-paypal-com-nvp-is-not-responding) about some kind of AT&T problem. but since I'm not a USA user, I doubt my provider is routing throught AT&T. Especially since, all our other servers with the same provider work well with this Api.

any clues about this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the request you're submitting that returns the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem **is** the [AT&T vs Paypal routing problem](http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?207238-%2828%29-connect%28%29-timed-out-https-api-3t-paypal-com-nvp-is-not-responding).
followed a `tracert` from our servers and saw the request stuck in the sprint router somewhere in new-york. working with my provider to solve this and reroute the requests.

I thought by now computers would be more reliable than this.